# Socket disconnecting on the first time

Tags: c#, asyncsocket

I am using a library on [Github](https://github.com/LankMasterFlex/MaplePacketLib/tree/master/MaplePacketLib/MaplePacketLib) to connect to a server, since I am not familiar with sockets in C#. The syntax for making a connection is just:

```
Connector con = new Connector(ip, port, cipher);
con.Connect();
```

The cipher parameter is just form of encryption that the server uses and is irrelevant for my question, I think.

After I call the Connect() method the library makes an asynchronized socked and I am not quite sure what happens after that. My question is that frequently when I build my application and try to connect to the server, I get disconnected on the first attempt only. Then if I try to connect again the program works fine. I was able to trace the source of the problem to the callback method of socket.BeginReceive here:

```
private void Receive() {
    if (m_connected) {
        var error = SocketError.Success;

        m_socket.BeginReceive(m_recvBuffer, 0, ReceiveSize, SocketFlags.None, out error, PacketCallback, null);

        if (error != SocketError.Success) {
            Disconnect();
        }
    }
}

private void PacketCallback(IAsyncResult iar) {
    if (m_connected) {
        var error = SocketError.Success;
        int length = m_socket.EndReceive(iar, out error);

        if (length == 0 || error != SocketError.Success) {
            Disconnect();
        }
        else {
            Append(length);
            ManipulateBuffer();
            Receive();
        }
    }
}
```

socket.EndReceive is returning a length of 0 which is causing the program to disconnect with SocketError.ConnectionReset. I just can't seem to figure out why it is only happening only on my first connection attempt. Every subsequent connection attempt works fine. Can someone who is familiar with sockets can tell me if it is an error in the library code, and a fix? If not, I would just have to assume it is an error on the server-side end. Thanks.

---

Comment: What server are you connecting to? How did you make sure the server is not disconnecting?

Comment: @usr That is exactly what I was wondering. I have no way of knowing whether the server is disconnecting me or not. That's why if I know that the library does not have any problems, I can conclude that the problem is just out of my control.

Comment: OK, write your own socket program to do that. Use synchronous IO. It's quite simple to do that if you don't need to total correctness but just a test.

Comment: @usr By synchronous do you mean connect instead of beginConnect?

Comment: Yes, that's simpler. Post the code

Answer (score -1):

Don't use socket helpers. Socket is very easy to use in .net.

Take a look at this msdn example :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx

Use the code in the above link. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: ??? Sockets are super hard to use. There are countless possible mistakes, I see the carnage every day. This answer tells me that you have never written a correct socket application. Also, it is not an answer.

Comment: Looking at this MSDN sample now. This is one of the most horrible MSDN samples there are. This code is an abomination.

Comment: I don't think so that socket is super hard on .net. There are a lot of help available for scokets. Superhard is something that you are not able to find help for it :)